# OAuth - DocuSign Log in page says 'The client id provided is not registered with DocuSign.'

Tags: docusignapi

I am new to the DocuSign integration.  It seems I need to use the OAuth Authorization Code Grant so I am doing a GET with something like this:

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code,&scope=signature,&client_id=my_integrator_key,&state=some_string,&redirect_uri=my_callback_URL
```

I have set the Redirect_URI on the Integrator Key to be the same value as my_callback_URL above, and I have set a Secret Key (though I do not know what that is for).

When the logon page displays it shows this error in red above the email address box:

> The client id provided is not registered with DocuSign.

I have spent quite some time trying to figure out why this is but no luck.  I figure this is a common mistake but I do not see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your redirect url is not right--do not include commas.

Your example should be:

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=my_integrator_key&state=some_string&redirect_uri=my_callback_URL
```

Once your redirect_uri is called with the `authorization code`, you'll use your `secret` when requesting a bearer token for use with your API calls.

[See the docs.](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_auth_code.html)

Comment: Thanks Larry.  That was the problem and it is now working!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `my_callback_URL` query parameter corresponds to a valid redirect URI you configured, and seeing that you are hitting the demo OAuth endpoint, are you possibly trying to use the production system?

To login to DocuSign's demo (sandbox) environment you go through:

https://account-d.docusign.com/#/web/login

To login to your live production account go through:

https://account.docusign.com/#/web/login

Comment: Thanks for responding on this.

I do not have anything setup for Production - I just started a few weeks ago in the sandbox.

I just do not know what would cause this particular error to show on the end user login page.

As far as the Redirect URI, if I copy the URL setup in the Sandbox and paste it in a browser, I get a hit to my callback program.  To me that proves it works - is that correct?

Comment: It shows up on the login page because if you do not have a proper redirect configured then the system does not where to redirect user on successful login.  To configure a redirectURI (which is case-sensitive) login to your sandbox, go to API and Keys page, then select the Integrator Key and click Edit.  You can then add redirect Uris through the pop up.